# Can I use form "What I like" in a article?

Tags: phrase-usage, free-relative-clauses

Can I use "What I like" or "What I dislike" as a title of a paragraph?

Should I instead use "What do I (dis)like"?

Comment: I think this question is Primarily Opinion-Based (either that or it's Off Topic writing advice).

Comment: I think if you provided an example where you saw this phrase and why you are questioning its usage, we could possibly help you better.

Comment: I think you can use pretty much anything you want as a paragraph heading. Most of the time, I would favor brevity, so, of the candidates you've provided, I'd vote for the shorter forms.

Comment: It seems to me that OP isn't asking which title is better but what syntactical forms are acceptable in a title. An earlier [question](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/6866/is-it-grammatically-correct-to-remove-the-from-the-beginning-of-a-photo-title) suggested that other languages or cultures might follow a narrower model than English does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### What I (dis)like

would make a reasonable title for an article.

### What do I (dis)like

sounds like a question.  It could also be a title, if it ends with a question mark, but has different connotations.  It sounds more engaging--like you're going to engage the reader in a discussion about what you like and why--sort of an exploration of the topic of what you like or dislike.

The former, **What I (dis)like** sounds like you'll just provide a list, possibly with short explanations of each item.

Comment: So maybe if I am writing a review it would be better to use "What do I like?". In the chapter I would explain my view and opinions.

Answer (score 5):

*What I like* and *What I dislike* are what are called ‘free relative’ constructions. Syntactically they act like nouns or Noun Phrases, so using them as titles is just as proper as using an ordinary Noun Phrase like *The Hobbit* or *Hamlet, Prince of Denmark* or *Harry Potter and the Philosopher's Stone*. Bernard Shaw titled one of his books *What I Really Wrote About the War*, and a famous story by Eudora Welty is titled “Why I Live at the P.O.”

*What do I like* is a sentence--specifically, a question. Questions, too, have been used as titles: *What Is To Be Done?*, *What Is Literature?*, *Where in the World is Carmen Sandiego?* But if you use a question as a title you should be sure to include the question mark.